# Is it possible to detect if an Android phone has a trackball?

Tags: android, trackball

My application requires users to hold down the trackball in order to access an advanced menu.  Not all phones have a trackball, however, so I need to remove this requirement for such phones.  Is there a way to detect if the phone has a trackball?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`Configuration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) object, specifically the `navigation` and `navigationHidden` fields. You can get a `Configuration` object via `getResources().getConfiguration()`.

Comment: This isn't really an answer... HOW do the navigation and navigationHidden fields help??

Comment: @Rich Presumably check if navigation is NAVIGATION_TRACKBALL (possibly allow NAVIGATION_DPAD too), indicating that a trackball (or D-pad) exists, and navigationHidden is not NAVIGATIONHIDDEN_YES, indicating that the trackball is not currently covered up by a folding/sliding mechanism.